# %HOMEPATH% as link when sending emails

Tags: email, explorer

Is it possible to send dynamic links via email? We store a lot of our files in DropBox and everyone has a dynamic file location due to their Home Path.
i.e.

```
<a href='%HOMEPATH%\DropBox Folder\Folder\File.xlsx'> Click Here </a>
```

Comment: You either need to process the template yourself and substitute variables like `%HOMEPATH%` or your email software can do that. The details depend on what you use to build your messages or what smtp server / provider you use. This is basic email personalization.

Comment: We use Gmail within Microsoft Outlook

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no; there is no portable and reliable way to specify relative paths which depend on the recipient's local file system in HTML without the recipient's active cooperation.